# Parent-child query

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose A is parent type and B is child type.

Now B has a field named 'event'.

At time t1, B1 (a 'B' type doc) was indexed with field 'event' = success against some parent 'A1'. Now at time t2 another doc B2 was indexed with 'event' = fail against same parent 'A1'.

What I have to do is find all parents which doesn't have any child or have only 'event' = success child (not a single 'event'=fail child). Is this possible?

One solution I can see is update my parent(A1) with some flag whenever 'event'=fail containing doc is indexed. But my B type docs also have a ingestion_time field. So I want to find parents which never got 'event'=fail containing child in the given time range.

Comment: You can use `has_child` query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/has-child.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "has_child": {
                    "type": "b",
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "event": "fail"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should exclude all parents that have children with `fail` field value

Comment: Yaah. Exactly same query hit me after posting this question.
Anyways thanks. :)
Marked it as answer.